# docker-py: Create container with specific IP in IPvlan Network

Tags: docker, dockerpy, docker-network

I created a network with driver: ipvlan and several subnets with specific gateways in it. (about 20)

Now i want to create containers with specific IP's, so that they get assign to the right subnet of the ipvlan network only!

```
     dockernetwork = client.networks.get('ipvlan172')
     print "create container with ip "+targetIP
     client.containers.run('myalpine',auto_remove=True,command='ping 192.168.11.11',detach=True,name=targetName)
     dockernetwork.connect(container,ipv4_address=targetIP)
     container.start()
```

What happens here is, that *client.containers.run* give the container an ip of the docker bridge network and the default gateway to the docker bridge.
Then *dockernetwork.connect* gives the container's interface a second ip (target ip).

If i add the parameter network='ipvlan172' to the command:

```
client.containers.run('myalpine',network='ipvlan172',auto_remove=True,command='ping 192.168.11.11',detach=True,name=targetName)
```

The created container does not get an ip of the docker bridge network, which i intended, **but** the targetIP of the command

```
dockernetwork.connect(container,ipv4_address=targetIP)
```

will be ignored. So that the created Container has an IP of a random subnet of the ipvlan network

One way to solve this, is to create a script which will be executed after the start of the container and deletes the dockerhost ip and changes the default gateway.

Are there other solutions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Okay i found out what you need to do in this case.

First u create the container without parameter *network=ipvlanXX*, so that the container gets a connection to the docker bridge.

Then u connect the container to the network of your choice, in my case ipvlan172.

```
dockernetwork.connect(container,ipv4_address=targetIP)
```

Afterwards you disconnect the container of the docker bridge network.

```
network_dockerbridge.disconnect(container,force=True)
```

And finally start the container.

```
container.start()
```

The created container has now the correct ip and uses the gateway of the correct subnet of the ipvlan network.

It would be nice to have an ipv4/ipv6 parameter in the run/create implementation of the dockerpy modul.